Blank browser page after ASP.NET Core spa startup
I am building spa app using ASP.NET Core with standard Vue template and a Minimal api. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (v17.11.4).
I am getting a blank browser page in new window after app startup without debugging. This page should display client part (vue) of the app.
What I am noticed is that browser window is not personalized. It doesn't have any my browser bookmarks or extensions.
When I put url in address bar of another working browser window that has all my settings, all works as expected. Incognito window also displays the page.
Edge and chrome were used with same result. Cache and cookie were cleared.

When I launch ASP.NET Core MVC app, then page is opened in existing browser window without any problem. I want the same behavior with spa app.

It isn't quite clear what you're asking.  If it is working as expected with a certain browser configuration and not with a plain vanilla one, then perhaps there is a configuration setting that's affect it?  In this case, it's more of a browser configuration issue and not a programming issue.

@ewokx I updated my question. When I launch another app that uses asp.net core mvc, then a page is opened in existing browser window and works fine. I don't have any specific browser configuration. Somehow plain non personalized window opens after spa startup.

Would it be ok if you refresh the page?

@ruikai-feng refresh doesn't help. It keeps endless loading.

You may try follow this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-vue?view=vs-2022#set-the-project-properties  ,Uncheck the Launch Browser option of server project for the https profile

@ruikai-feng It doesn't help. Last time I tried to disable client (vue) startup project in solution settings. In this case vue is launching but i need to open page manually. This is not solution but it is better then before.
